# Fullpage.js elements scroll horizontally at different speeds

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, fullpage.js

How can you make elements in a slide scroll at different speeds horizontally when you trigger autoscroll with the mouse/keyboard? Like a parallax effect so that elements move faster than the background. Forget the code below (required to post) as it wont display correctly for some reason, but you can see example of horizontal scrolling on the second slide [here](https://codepen.io/fahmy/pen/NYMNEJ) I just want to target 1 element and make that move faster than the background. The parallax extension wont work for this as the background needs to stay exactly as it is, I just need the element on top to move faster...

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
  anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
  menu: '#menu',
  slidesNavigation: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-slimScroll/1.3.1/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage">First slide</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Second slide</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage">Third slide</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="4thpage"><a href="#4thpage">Fourth slide</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="section0">
        <h1>fullPage.js</h1>
        <p>Create Beautiful Fullscreen Scrolling Websites</p>
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/fullPage.png" alt="fullPage" />
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section1">
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="intro">
                <h1>Create Sliders</h1>
                <p>Not only vertical scrolling but also horizontal scrolling. With fullPage.js you will be able to add horizontal sliders in the most simple way ever.</p>
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/slider.png" alt="slider" />
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="intro">
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/1.png" alt="simple" />
                <h1>Simple</h1>
                <p>Easy to use. Configurable and customizable.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="intro">
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/2.png" alt="Cool" />
                <h1>Cool</h1>
                <p>It just looks cool. Impress everybody with a simple and modern web design!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="intro">
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/3.png" alt="Compatible" />
                <h1>Compatible</h1>
                <p>Working in modern and old browsers too! IE 8 users don't have the fault of using that horrible browser! Lets give them a chance to see your site in a proper way!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Example</h1>
            <p>HTML markup example to define 4 sections.</p>
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/example2.png" alt="example" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section3">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Working On Tablets</h1>
            <p>
                Designed to fit to different screen sizes as well as tablet and mobile devices.
                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            </p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/tablets.png" alt="tablets" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe you can probably use the parallax extension for that. Just invert the things.
Add your text on the `fp-bg` element and then the background directly as a background of the section. I haven't tried it, but it might do it :)

Comment: im actually using the elementor plugin, would this be achievable?

Comment: Mmm a bit more tricky there... i would say not without editing HTML :)